# When i click outside of the modal second time its closing first time its not closing. I don't want to close that modal

Tags: bootstrap-modal

The first time I click on add button modal is showing.
After clicking on remove button it is closing. 
When I repeat the same scenario clicking on add button the modal is showing but after that clicking outside the modal is getting it closed.

I use bootstrap css.I didnt implemented this functionality.

```
           <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPopup" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
          <div class="modal fade" id="modalPopup" tabindex="2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="item-quantity" aria-hidden="true"> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your button's close tag `</button>`. Try this

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPopup" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Test</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalPopup" tabindex="2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="item-quantity" aria-hidden="true"> 

</div>
```